# Jquery submit not working to submit into the action servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I'm having trouble to submit the form by clicking button in another form.When i hit the button,it is not redirected to the action servlet, but it redirects into the same page,with a url like this,

> http://localhost:8080/OnlineDD/index.jsp/login.jsp?

with a *'?'* at the end.This method was working in my sample project.

**HTML code**

```
<form autocomplete="off">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus type="text" required="" id="emailIDForm1">

    </label>
    </div>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input autocomplete="off" type="password" min="6" required="" id="logPassId" />

    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="submitForm" class="btn btn-primary">LOGIN</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
<form action="LoginServlet" method="post" id="SecFormLogin" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="emailId" id="emailIdForm2" />
    <input type="password" name="password" id="passForm2" />
</form>
```

and **Jquery** code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#logPassId').change(function() {
            var password= $(this).val();
            $('#passForm2').val(password );
        });
        $('#emailIDForm1').change(function() {
            var email= $(this).val();
            $('#emailIdForm2').val(email);
        });
        $("#submitForm").click(function() {
            $("#SecFormLogin").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

and **Servlet** code is,

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Called post");}
```

Comment: This approach makes no sense. Check section "Ajaxifying an existing form" in the above linked duplicate

Comment: Iam not intented to use Ajax,it is just a part of my project(for encryption for password).My intention is as per the question and is different from the duplicated,it is to make the action of another form on button click from another form.Thankyou for noticing this question.

Comment: I made it correct.It was to use  `<input type="button" id="submitFormButton" value="LOGIN"/>` instead of `<button id="submitForm" class="btn btn-primary">LOGIN</button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have Deployment Descriptor (web.xml)

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>servletName</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>packageName.servletName</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>servletName</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/yourServletUrl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Or you may use annotations in your Servlet since servlets 3.0.

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet(name = "servletName", urlPatterns = { "/yourServletUrl" })
public class servletName extends HttpServlet {
```

Comment: I have already added the details in web.xml.Still not working.!

Comment: This answer is wrong. If the URL mapping was indeed missing, OP would have faced a HTTP 404 error when hitting the servlet, but this is not the case.

Comment: Sorry.By mistake, i voted up.

Comment: Yeah.Thank you for helping.